# Backbone why is change called on save?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone model that I want to update locally, but I don't know if the update is going to change anything in the model.

I don't want to run `set` on the model and call a `save` right after, as nothing might have changed.

So ideally, I just listen for a `change` event and then save it:

```
var Goat = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.on('change', function(){
      this.save();
    });
  }

});

var billy = new Goat({
  gruff: true
});

billy.set('gruff', true); // doesn't do anything
billy.set('gruff', false); // fires change
```

The problem with this is that calling save then apparently fires `change`, and so we go in the exciting endless circle.

Why would `save` trigger `change`? And if this is so, what is the correct way for me to achieve the above?

Comment: Clarify your goal: Whenever a model property changes you want to persist the model?

Comment: Yes. Without having to check if the model is different beforehand and without creating a 'change'-'save' loop.

Comment: Okay, FYI: the model checks if the current model is different every time you `set()` or `save()`. http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-46

Comment: Typically people just call `save()` in their views. Why not do this in your case?

Comment: Are you persisting to local storage, or AJAX to a server?

Comment: Supposing the last two lines of my code are in my view, I don't want to run save on the first one, but I don't know if I am setting 'gruff' to true or false.

Comment: I am running AJAX to the server.

Comment: Why not run `save()` on the first? I missing the reason.

Comment: @WillM, My guess would be to avoid making an ajax request for a model that didn't change.

Comment: Well, what if the model was since changed on the server from a different tab (or by a different user, etc)? The AJAX request is still needed to ensure the value is true after the first .set().

Comment: Pretty sure `backbone` checks if the persisted model has changed on the server: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-61

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that attaching `save` to a `change` event is such a good idea (I'm not sure it *isn't* a good idea either – I suppose it depends on the situation), but in answer to your question, you can check whether the model `hasChanged` before saving. You can read more about this in the Backbone documentation [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-hasChanged).

```
var Goat = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.on('change', function() {
      if (this.hasChanged()) {
        this.save();
      }
    });
  }
});
```